# Searching through a list of numbers which came from mysql query result

Tags: php

```
$save_planet3 = "SELECT saver_id FROM save_planet 
                WHERE saver_id = '".($_SESSION['user_id'])."' 
                AND map = 1 ORDER BY time_saved DESC";
$save_planet2 = mysql_query($save_planet3) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);   

while ($list = mysql_fetch_array($save_planet2)) { 
  $saver_id = $list['saver_id'];
```

When I `echo $saver_id` I'm getting a list of numbers

3112   3112   3112   3112
I'm trying to do a check if `$planet_id` is equal to any of these numbers

So I figure the only way to do this is to put these numbers in an array with keys first. So I tried to explode it but it doesn't give each one a different key I noticed.

```
$check = explode(",", $saver_id);
print_r($check); 


Array ( [0] => 3112 )
Array ( [0] => 3112 )
Array ( [0] => 3112 )
Array ( [0] => 3112 )
```

Once I get this in a workable array I should be able to do this right

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {    
  if ($planet_id == $value) { 
  //something happends
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not store the result set values into an array inside of the while loop?

```
$arr = array();
while ($list = mysql_fetch_array($save_planet2)) { 
  $saver_id = $list['saver_id']; 
  $arr[] = $saver_id;
}

print_r($arr);
```

You can also use `in_array()` to check for the value existence.